# What are the pros and cons selling NFT using the ETH on Polygon?

Tags: blockchain, polygon, opensea

I know sellers are trying to avoid the gas fee on OpenSea by using the polygon blockchain.
What are the pros and cons of both buyer and seller?

Comment: Cheaper gas fees, basically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pros

- cheaper transaction costs
- faster transactions.

Cons

- your assets are less secure. Do you trust polygon to not lose your funds?

Comment: Thank you, @Arsen Akishev. For ETH on Polygon, does it mean the buyer pay with ETH and seller received in Polygon?

Comment: On polygon you can pay with ETH or Matic. It's really up to the platform accepting the purchase.